# Windows 7, cpu at 100%, netsh.exe, node.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu

I'm having a strange problem with my cpu usage. I've seen similar complaints elsewhere, but no real solution. Whatever software I am using, my CPU seems to max out to 100% with seemingly useless operations (see picture, node.exe, netsh.exe (Terminated!), and WMIC.exe). On googling I found that there is a known bug for WMI, but due to lack of resources I've been unable to install the fix.

The computer is slow with almost any operation now, so I am unable to properly google the answer. It seems that even from a public link, the browser can't reach imgur to upload a screenshot. So here is just the link to the resource monitor capture:
[image]

Any idea what could be the cause, hardware or software? What more information would you need? Many many thanks!!

I have other software open, but nothing out of the ordinary, which steps should I follow to get to the bottom of this.

**Update:**

I replaced a misbehaving AVG antivirus for a brief benefit which disappeared quickly, here's the baseline I am looking at now:

With Chrome (but pretty much nothing else) running:

[image]

Without Chrome (almost nothing running):

[image]

The lag is much better with almost nothing open, but I'm still worried of how quickly the CPU fills up. Any tips welcome! The relative order of the processes taking CPU space fluctuates heavily.

**Update 2:**

The system now seems to have settled on occasional peaks with some more needed software running at the time. The noticable lag has decreased, but these peaks are still worrying. Any thoughts? Thanks!

[image]

**Update 3**

I found out, what was node.exe, it makes sense finally. System runs smoothly after removing it - so it was a software error after all. Reported it to the maintainers of the software, probably was some bug in their recent update. Thanks for the help, I hope it stays this way!

[image: Software issue solved!]

Comment: I have seen this type of issue twice with a bad power supply on a laptop.  Running on battery it was fine, but with the power supply connected there was 100% CPU utilization and it just switched between various processes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did see a small effect when returning from hibernation. Tried different powers settings plugged in and out, online or offline, but nothing longlasting, and it's back at 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that there are 2 issues. It is possible that they are related.

1. Chrome is using up 38% CPU
2. Node.exe is using up 32%

So between them 70% of your CPU is in constant use. On my laptop right now, I am showing 4-10% CPU.

It looks to me as though you have something very heavy running in Node.JS and I'd guess that your Chrome browser is connected to the Node server?

The easier one to deal with is Chrome. Kill off Chrome tabs/windows until the CPU for it drops. Then find out what is causing your Node.JS application to run at high CPU levels.

The netsh.exe levels may also be related to something you are doing in Node. Do you get the same problems if you are not running your node server?

I've just run up a node.js server running the Node-Red application and it isn't even registering any CPU usage even though I have the UI open in a browser window and it is constantly updating some debug information.

There is also a Windows Service that is using some significant CPU to as I can see the Services part showing at 13% which is fairly high. Is your node application connected to a database?

Comment: Thanks! This is most useful. After removing AVG, closing Chrome (it has a lot of tabs open, but I can't close them one by one just yet today) seems to free up CPU half the time (see above, while it still goes to almost 100% every few seconds, due to node. I can't figure out the origin of node though, - it seems that netsh.exe was tied directly to open chrome. I have to also add, that the order of applications in the CPU table fluctuates in less than a second, thus it may be 'node', 'WMI', 'svchost', or something else ('enet', 'copy', 'chrome') which is the top one (on peaks 30+% usually).

Comment: [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) is an application for running javascript programmes outside of a browser. It is unlikely that you have it installed without knowing that you'd done it. Have you installed a new application?

Comment: I've installed nothing recently, but it's possible that I haven't noticed the CPU issue for a while and accepting the mysterious lag as normal. Hmmh, now I'm running on the pace with just occasional peaks with all of chrome running... maybe it will go away on its own? Peaks are caused by node, WMI, and/or svchost for now.

Comment: You appear to have some strange services running. BFE implies the use of an IPSEC VPN or something else running encryption. EKRN implies NOD which you probably shouldn't be running along side AVG. Virtual Router is an internet sharing tool. So there is a lot going on in your PC. You really need to find out why node.js is running.

Comment: Adding the other bits of software that I need (a bunch of tabs on Foxit reader and a very large Word document) luckily doesn't change much, and the intolerable lag is mostly gone. Must be my lucky day, I've updated the performance report accordingly too.

Comment: Something is pretty wrong on your PC and I strongly recommend you continue to sort through the issues. You should not be seeing those CPU spikes. Even running a full screen movie (flash), 6 Windows in Firefox with 40-50 tabs, MongoDB and some other stuff I'm only getting around 20% CPU on my i7.

Comment: Ok, out of my depth on software awareness, but my computer has been acting up lately (some issues with not being able to access files on harddrive on some moments in time - these have disappeared now). Oh, I used Virtual Router a while ago, but thought I had removed it from startup, I haven't seen any evidence of the application running for a while, good to remove it. I just installed ESET ekrn instead of AVG just now, it seems to be more stable. Not sure about BFE, I use a virtual proxy for uni networks on my chrome though. Anything else could be only from ESET.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I definitely want to get to the bottom of this, though I may not be able to do all the work for it in a week or two due to actual work expected. Could this be a hardware issue too? Maybe a technical review of it might help out...

Comment: I strongly recommend you go through all of your installed software and remove everything you don't need. I also recommend you go through your startup list and services and disable everything you don't need. Those spikes are pretty bad.

Comment: It is possible that it is hardware but honestly, I think it unlikely. Much more likely to be software. It is too regular.

Comment: Wow! It took a while, but I finally found out what 'node' was! Fun stuff, it was an anti-theft system that's exactly supposed to be ultra secretive in these process menus. Could be a recent update, as it really shouldn't be what it was meant for - I'll report this to them! Updated the picture above with the most recent one, nice and fixed! Thanks a lot, wouldn't have checked all these details without you!

Comment: No problem, glad you've fixed it.